# I am not able to register new ENS name in Ethereum Name Service

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, ether

I am using JS library [Web3 JS](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/)
My aim is to register a new ENS name like "demo1234.eth" on Ropsten Test Network

I tried

setResolver

```
web3.eth.ens.setResolver('demo1234.eth', '0xBDA997B9532ce5e98CF7090f87f24dC11bb42F63',{from:'0xBDA997B9532ce5e98CF7090f87f24dC11bb42F63'}, (data)=>{console.log(data)});
```

setOwner

```
web3.eth.ens.setOwner('demo1234.eth', {from:'0xBDA997B9532ce5e98CF7090f87f24dC11bb42F63'}, (data)=>{console.log(data)});
```

setAddress

```
web3.eth.ens.setAddress('demo1234.eth','0xBDA997B9532ce5e98CF7090f87f24dC11bb42F63', {from:'0xBDA997B9532ce5e98CF7090f87f24dC11bb42F63'}, (data)=>{console.log(data)});
```

setRecord

```
web3.eth.ens.setRecord('demo1234.eth','0x283Af0B28c62C092C9727F1Ee09c02CA627EB7F5 ','0xBDA997B9532ce5e98CF7090f87f24dC11bb42F63',3600 {from:'0xBDA997B9532ce5e98CF7090f87f24dC11bb42F63'}, (data)=>{console.log(data)});
```

I am able to do send transaction to metamask wallet and after approval given to transaction it get failed after some time i am getting same error

```
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
```

[reference](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x58dec8012d2d7f39240333069a133bfc581ce044b7a689e245ed4fe09ee39b62)

even I tried to deploy a similar contract I found [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x283af0b28c62c092c9727f1ee09c02ca627eb7f5#code)

I am getting same error .

I have my wallet 0xBDA997B9532ce5e98CF7090f87f24dC11bb42F63 on Ropsten Test Nework ,Even I have enough balance in my wallet (approx 8.4 eth)
please if any one know how can I successfully register new ENS name on test net How I registered on [ens.domain](https://app.ens.domains/)

please guys help me if you can ... and

thank you so much in advance